# Is it OK to use two “them” meaning different things?

Tags: grammar

> I made cookies for Mike and Jack. They will come to my house to eat them.

Doesn’t this sound strange?

Answer (score 1):

It is not wrong, but in this context it is only mildly confusing, because the cookies definitely cannot eat Mike and Jack - the listener only needs to concentrate a little to get the right meaning.

However, in other context, the confusion could be maximum, because one could not be sure who mkaes the action, and who is the target of said action.

Answer (score 0):

That particular sentence sounds almost normal to me. It has a slight twinge of confusion, but not much at all. (It's mainly exaggerated by considering the question itself.) Because of how it's constructed, it's quite clear what each pronoun is referring to.

The most typical way of rephrasing it would be to turn it into a single sentence as follows:

> I made cookies for Mike and Jack, **who** will come to my house to eat them.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to do that as long as there's no ambiguity. Since we know who's doing the eating and what's being eaten, the meaning is clear. There's nothing wrong with that sentence.